# Trouble checking for whether ruby hash contains certain fields populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm writing a test case to ensure that all key fields such as total_interactions, shares, comments and likes are keys that exist in the hash.

Not sure why I get this exception:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for ["total_interactions", {"value"=>1170.0}]:Array
```

Here is the hash that I'm checking in:

```
{13=>{"total_interactions"=>{"value"=>1170.0}, "shares"=>{"value"=>850.0}, "comments"=>{"value"=>0.0}, "likes"=>{"value"=>320.0}}, 17=>{"total_interactions"=>{"value"=>701.0}, "shares"=>{"value"=>300.0}, "comments"=>{"value"=>0.0}, "likes"=>{"value"=>401.0}}, 12=>{"total_interactions"=>{"value"=>203.66666666666666}, "shares"=>{"value"=>100.66666666666667}, "comments"=>{"value"=>0.0}, "likes"=>{"value"=>103.0}}, 22=>{"total_interactions"=>{"value"=>11.0}, "shares"=>{"value"=>2.0}, "comments"=>{"value"=>0.0}, "likes"=>{"value"=>9.0}}}
```

Here is the method that is supposed to do this.

```
def test_aggs_response_populated(aggs_results)
    aggs_results.each do |k,v|
        if(v.class == Hash)
            contains_interactions = false
            contains_shares = false
            contains_comments = false
            contains_likes = false

            v.each do |hash_item|
                contains_interactions = hash_item.has_key?("total_interactions")
                contains_shares = hash_item.has_key?("shares")
                contains_comments = hash_item.has_key?("comments")
                contains_likes = hash_item.has_key?("likes")
            end

            assert_equal(true, contains_interactions)
            assert_equal(true, contains_shares)
            assert_equal(true, contains_comments)
            assert_equal(true, contains_likes)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the reason for the Rails tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the hash twice. You dont want to use has_key on the key/value pair.

You should change

```
v.each do |hash_item|
    contains_interactions = hash_item.has_key?("total_interactions")
    contains_shares = hash_item.has_key?("shares")
    contains_comments = hash_item.has_key?("comments")
    contains_likes = hash_item.has_key?("likes")
end
```

to

```
contains_interactions = v.has_key?("total_interactions")
contains_shares = v.has_key?("shares")
contains_comments = v.has_key?("comments")
contains_likes = v.has_key?("likes")
```